# Adding fractions in two ways - a paradox?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Adding 1/3 to 2/3 gives 1 EXACTLY. But expanding the two fractions and then adding gives 0.99999
Where is the flaw in this reasoning?

Comment: It is the same flaw which states $\frac{1}{3}=0.3333...$

Comment: $0.99999\ldots=1$ *exactly*.

Comment: This question has been asked before under the guise of "why does .999... = 1?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw is that you assumed the sequence of digits in $0.99999\ldots$ terminates at some point.  It doesn't.  The sequence $0.99999\ldots$ is
$$
\frac 9 {10} + \frac 9 {100} + \frac 9 {1000} + \frac 9 {10000} + \cdots
$$
and by the usual method of finding the sum of an infinite geometric series, that adds up to $1$, exactly.

Notice that $0.33333$, terminating after five digits, is not exactly $1/3$ either.  If the sequence of $3$s terminates at some point, then it's less than $1/3$.  You can make it as close as you want to $1/3$ by making the number of $3$s big enough.

(I think various slight variations on the theme of this question have been posted here a number of times.)